# How to get DocumentDB Disk Usage without Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Our `Azure DocumentDB` is managed by a different team. We don't have access to the `Azure Portal`. Is there a way for us to see the disk usage of a `DocumentCollection`? A **REST API** or **.NET API**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use client.ReadDocumentCollectionAsync to get this information, e.g.,

```
ResourceResponse<DocumentCollection> response = 
    await client.ReadDocumentCollectionAsync(collectionLink);
Console.WriteLine(response.CollectionSizeQuota); 
Console.WriteLine(response.CollectionSizeUsage);
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.readdocumentcollectionasync.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn799209.aspx for more details.

The equivalent in the REST API is the x-ms-* response headers from GET collection.

Comment: I tried this code snippet on my local DocumentDB emulator instance but the result is 0. Am I missing something or is this not supported in the response of the Azure DocumentDB emulator?

Comment: I'll double-check. We might need to update the emulator.